# Is it possible to construct the equation of a surface from its line element?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, parametric, parametrization

**If you are given the [line element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element) (or, for that matter, the [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) or [area element](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AreaElement.html)) on a two-dimensional surface, is it possible to determine an equation for that surface in three-dimensions?**

For example, if I were to give you the line element on a sphere (namely, $(ds)^2=R^2(d\phi)^2+R^2\sin^2(\phi)(d\theta)^2$), how would you deduce that the equation for that surface is either
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2+(z-l)^2=R^2
$$
or
$$x=R\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)+h\\y=R\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)+k\\z=R\cos(\phi)+l
$$
for any $h,\ k,\text{ and }l$ (the sphere's center), $0\leq \phi\leq \pi$ (the azimuthal angle), and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ (the polar angle)?

Comment: To the person who edited the line element equation, you are thinking of the line element in spherical coordinates in 3D space. This question is asking about a surface. The line element for a curve constrained to the surface of a sphere does not contain $(dr)^2$.

Comment: This is the problem of isometric embedding, and there's not really a short answer. Some abstract surfaces can't be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ at all (e.g. the hyperbolic plane), and in general there can be nontrivial non-uniqueness (e.g. the flat square $du^2 + dv^2, 0<u,v<1$ can be embedded as part of a flat plane but also as part of a cylinder). You're always going to have the trivial kind of non-uniqueness - in your example you accounted for translations with $h,k,l$ but forgot about rotations of the sphere.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Okay, I take your meaning. This is helpful since I do tend to ask questions that are sometimes overly broad. Allow me to put it this way: Suppose we restrict our attention to certain well-behaved deformations of the sphere (like axially symmetric metrics $(ds)^2=(d\phi)^2+f^2(\phi)(d\theta)^2$ where $f$ is sufficently smooth, etc.). Would specifying f specify the surface (modulo trivial differences)?

Comment: If you choose $f$ so that $ds^2$ has positive Gaussian curvature then yes - this is the rigidity theorem of Cohn-Vossen. (If "deformation of the sphere" implies that the values of $f$ and its first few derivatives are very close to those of $\sin$, then this should work.) Without any restriction, no - choosing $f = \sinh$ gives the hyperbolic plane counterexample.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you! This has given me plenty to look into.